# How to Reactjs Link to and onclick event handling at once?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hello I have problem with React-router Link component. I am using Link to function and onClick event handler. Like this:

```
  logout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    auth.logout();
  }

    <Link to="/" onClick={this.logout}>Sing Out</Link>
```

Event handler working, but I am not redirected. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approach #1;

Try removing the `event` `preventDefault()`

```
logout = (e) => {
   // e.preventDefault(); => You don't need this
   auth.logout();
}

<Link to="/" onClick={this.logout}>Sing Out</Link>
```

Approach #2

```
logout = (e) => {
  auth.logout();
  this.props.history.push('/');
}

<span onClick={this.logout}>Sing Out</span>
```

For approach 2, If this is the main Router component, react router will inject the `history` prop, but if this is a component inside the router component then you will have to wrap this in a higher order component like this

At the top where you include packages

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
```

At the bottom where you export your component

```
export default withRouter(YourComponentName)
```

For reference [withRouter documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter)

Comment: Caveat: do not use a `span` tag as a link in production, this creates all manner of accessibility and usability issues. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/link_role#best_practices and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML and

Answer (score 3):

In your case you will need to use a normal `button` instead of `Link`

Then onClick of the button call this function

```
logout = (e) => {
    auth.logout();
    this.props.history.push('/')
  }
```

If your are communicating with server then you can use promises

```
logout = (e) => {
    auth.logout().then(()=>{
     this.props.history.push('/')
    });

  }
```

Incase you are not getting `history` prop in your component, use `withRouter` higher order component and wrap your component with it. This happens if your cmponent is not a direct child of the main router.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

...your code


export default withRouter(YourComponentName);
```